# importError using a virtualenv from cmd on Windows

Tags: python, cmd, flask, virtualenv, pycharm

trying to run a flask dev server on localhost:5000 using a virtualenv on Windows 7

In my command line in the project directory, i activated the virtualenv with the command "env\scripts\activate".  It seemed to work, as my next line was preceded with an (env) tag.  When I attempted to run the app file (bank_app), however, I got an import error.

Here's the console log

```
C:\Users\TJ\Documents\Python Projects\TestingPython> env\scripts\activate
(env) C:\Users\TJ\Documents\Python Projects\TestingPython> bank_app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TJ\Documents\Python Projects\TestingPython\bank_app.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

and [here's a gist of the bank_app file](https://gist.github.com/HeliosJack/7a74ce30235e1d39830f) (just in case it's relevant)

I'm used to running the code directly from PyCharm, which handles the virtualenv for me. it works fine running directly from PyCharm

Comment: Have you installed flask in virtaulenv ?

Comment: @Fledgling Yes.  When running the application from pycharm, which uses the virtualenv as its interpreter, the application runs, no error produced..

Comment: Activate virtaulenv and then then start python, using python command and then try to `import flask` see what happens

Comment: @Fledgling import produced no errors.   I tried to put the console output in this comment, but I don't know how to preserve newlines.

Comment: Are you sure you are using virtualenv with pycharm or you are running your application from command prompt with virtaulenv activated?

Comment: @Fledgling Well, by contrast, if I run python without activating virtualenv, trying to import flask raises an error.  And since the application runs without errors on PyCharm, I deduce that PyCharm is using the virtualenv.  Is there some way I can verify this for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably related to how Windows maps extensions to executables.

You started the script with `bank_app`, which is really not the name of your script (your script has a `.py` extension I assume?). Windows must be doing a search in your directory, and then starting the script with the interpreter that is registered for the `.py` extension of the script, which is the globally installed interpreter, not the interpreter that is currently in the `PATH`.

I'm pretty sure if you run the command as `python bank_app.py` everything will work just fine.

Comment: Unbelievable.  Worked.  Thank you.  I really ought to switch to linux just to avoid these minor crises.

Comment: You can make Windows a bit more decent if you use [babun](http://babun.github.io/).

Comment: That's brilliant.  I've been shopping for a good shell.  Thanks!